# cannot obain the function return values via pointers

Tags: go, pointers, command-line-arguments

**Update 2021-9-26**
I found this is a stupid question.

This is because the flag will be updated after calling flag.Parse().

```
nReq := *flag_var
flag.Parse() // flag_var update
fmt.Println(nReq) // nReq is unchanged.
```

Thus, the best practice is to use flag.IntVar() instead and we can type fewer chars.

---

Why can't I use the points types of return values like this?

```
// test.go
nReq := *flag.Int("n", 10000, "set total requests")
flag.Parse()
fmt.Println(nReq)

// test -n 200
10000
// the value is still 10000.
```

It always returns the default value(10000).
I need to use:

```
nReq := flag.Int("n", 10000, "set total requests")
flag.Parse()
fmt.Println(*nReq)

// test -n 200
200
// the value is updated to the new flag(200)
```

Comment: what's the different between val1 := * function() and val2 := *val1

Comment: It is stupid to write like this:    
val1 := func() *ptr, val2 := *val1. when I do not want to write *val1 every time.

Comment: nReq = *func() cannot actually get the new value of the flag. It is always the default value (10000). It may be due to the compile optimization.

Comment: The code snippet is from a large program and I omit the flag.Parse in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`flag.Int()`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#Int) does not parse the flag "immediately", it just returns a pointer to a variable where the flag value will be stored when parsed.

So you if you dereference it right away, you'll just get the default value you provided. You have to call [`flag.Parse()`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#Parse).

If you don't want to work with pointers, declare the variable prior, and use [`flag.IntVar()`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#IntVar), for example:

```
var nReq int
flag.IntVar(&nReq, "n", 10000, "set total requests")

flag.Parse()
fmt.Println(nReq)
```

Now `nReq` is not a pointer, you may use it without having to dereference all the time.

Another option is to keep using `int.Var()`, and dereference the returned pointer **once**, **after** `flag.Parse()` has been called:

```
nReqPtr := flag.Int("n", 10000, "set total requests")
flag.Parse()

nReq := *nReqPtr
fmt.Println(nReq)
```

Comment: It is terrible to use flag.IntVar especially when I have lots of arguments in different types.

Comment: You may dereference the pointer returned by `flag.Int()` once **after** `flag.Parse()`. See edit.

Comment: val1 := func() *ptr, val2 := *val1. This form is still not perfect. Why not the golang flag.Parse update the value via pointer?

Comment: @fripSide That's exactly what the `flag` package does if you use `flag.IntVar()`.

Comment: But flag.IntVar needs to declare the values first. It is a disaster to declares variables with different types. Things go well if we declare the same types together. But what's the meaning of return a default pointer in flag.Int ?

Comment: It's not returning a default pointer. It returns a pointer to a variable to which the default value is assigned. When you parse the flags with `flag.Parse()`, then the provided value will be assigned to that variable. If the flag is not present, the default value will remain in the pointed variable.